# ArgumentOutofRangeException was unhandled,"InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'."

Tags: c#

I have been getting this error "InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'."

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object lst=listView1.SelectedItems[0].Clone();
    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index);
    listView2.Items.Add((ListViewItem)lst);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update visitortb set checkstat=1 where passno=" + text_passno.Text + "", db.Connect());
    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Check OUT Complete");
    }
}
```

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: Does it happen when you have empty list?

Comment: Your SQL command looks like it would be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

You've haven't selected any items in the `ListView`.

The [`SelectedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is a collection of `ListViewItem` objects, and like any collection it's possible for it to be empty.

Check the `Count` property of collection first, before trying to access the first element.

```
if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
    return;

// rest of your code
```

Comment: That, or no *selected* items.

Comment: @Grant, I think you've mistyped the code. The code is intended to return when listView1.SelectedItems.Count is less than or equal to zero, i.e. "if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count <= 0) return;"

Comment: @Grant, Going to bed on time is a solution to that... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            object lst = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Clone();
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index);
            listView2.Items.Add((ListViewItem)lst);

            MessageBox.Show("Check OUT Complete");

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No item selected!");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two absolute reason and one of them is true:

```
1) The listView has no row
2) No item has been selected
```